# Authenticate to azure ad with JWT python sdk

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python

I need to authenticate to Azure AD to perform REST API calls.
I'm using Azure Python SDK (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python) for that.
I have another code that returns me the JWT (JSON Web Token) of the user.
How can I connect with this JWT?
I try to look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate?tabs=cmd
but I didn't find something useful

Answer (score 0):

To call the REST API secured by azure ad, just make an API call with python, pass the token you got to the request header.

As you don't mention the specific API you want to call, here is just an approximate sample, change the `url` to the API you want and change `requests.get` to the method you want, there are maybe other headers and bodies depend on the specific API, the `access_token` is the token you should pass.

```
import requests

url = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualnetworks?api-version=2015-06-15'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}

response = requests.get(url=url,headers = headers)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

**Note:** You don't provide the code you got the token, I don't know if it is correct, please make sure the audience of the token is correct and has the permission to call the corresponded API, otherwise you will get an error.

Reference:

[Making a request to a RESTful API using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301938/making-a-request-to-a-restful-api-using-python)

[How to make Raw REST Call for Azure using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300926/how-to-make-raw-rest-call-for-azure-using-python)

Comment: Thank you for your answer
but it doesn't use Azure python sdk

Comment: @Yossi You have already gotten the token, why it needs sdk? So what actually you want do do? Please include more details.